# Heroku Deployment Error: Failed to Push Some Refs to Git Repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, deployment

I'm encountering an issue while trying to deploy my Ruby on Rails application to Heroku. Despite following the standard deployment process, I'm stuck with the following error when I try to push my code to the Heroku remote:

```
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/stormy-reaches-25258.git'
```

This error appears after attempting to push my main branch to Heroku using the command:

```
git push heroku main
```

I've checked my `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` for any discrepancies, ensured my Ruby version is supported by Heroku, and even tried clearing the build cache, but the issue persists. Here are some details about my setup:

- Ruby version: ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin21]
- Rails version: Rails 7.0.4
- I've also ensured that my `Gemfile.lock` is up to date and committed to my repository.

Could someone help me understand what might be causing this error and how to resolve it? I'm relatively new to deploying Rails apps on Heroku and would appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

Comment: This is an issue that the branch you are pushing doesn’t have some commits that are on the server. Did you make changes directly on the server or did someone else push to the server?

Comment: Or maybe you rewrite your local history, e.g. by amending a commit or rebasing?